# Meaning of the phrase "at least initially"

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

What does the phrase "at least initially", as used in these examples, mean?

> The attention, at least initially, surprised them.
>
> At least initially, few donors seemed to agree.
>
> But the real gold, at least initially, is water.

Comment: Please read the "[Contributor's Guide to ELL](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4783/contributors-guide-to-english-language-learners/4785)" and [Details Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please).To improve your question: **what do you think the answer might be** and what research have you done?  Keep contributing and welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Initially" means "At the beginning", so "Initially few donors seemed to agree" means "At the beginning few donors seemed to agree" etc.

"at least" has several meanings but in this case it is being use to emphasise a good aspect of a bad situation. So "At least initially [something bad]" emphasises that the bad thing should not last forever.

Hence 
"At the beginning only a few donors seemd to agree though this situation did not last forever"

"At the beginning but not forever, the real gold is water"

"At the beginning but not forever, the attention suprised them" or maybe - it is ambiguous - it was the attention only lasted for a time rather than their surprise.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Can you elaborate, please?

Comment: Sorry - had hit return without realising before going off for lunch!! Edited now to finish it off.

Comment: OK, I now understand. Thanks so much!